How can I take a RAR file and dynamically generate a gallery in Node.js?
I need to create an HTML gallery dynamically without saving the files to disk. I need to retrieve data from individual RAR files or split RAR files (e.g., rar, r01, r02, r03, and so on) and generate a gallery with these images. I've tried everything but haven't had success. I managed to do this with Flask and Python, but I need it in Node.js.
I'm open to any solution, whether using Blob or Buffer, as long as I can achieve this goal.
I am providing two RAR files as examples here. Please note that I will be working with large files.
Example 1
example: rar, r01, r02
Example 2
example.rar
Sever:
  import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { createExtractorFromFile } from 'node-unrar-js';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Set up static directory to serve HTML and JS files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const rarFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'example_rar_5.rar');

// Route to get the list of images
app.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const extractor = await createExtractorFromFile({ filepath: rarFilePath });
        const extracted = extractor.extract();
        const files = [...extracted.files]; // Converting the generator to an array

        console.log('Extracted files:', files); // Adicionar este console.log para verificar a estrutura dos arquivos

        const imageFiles = files.filter(file => /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/.test(file.fileHeader.name));
        const imageFilenames = imageFiles.map(file => file.fileHeader.name);

        res.json(imageFilenames);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error listing images:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error processing the RAR file');
    }
});

// Route to serve images as Blob
app.get('/images/:filename', async (req, res) => {
    const filename = req.params.filename;

    try {
        const extractor = await createExtractorFromFile({ filepath: rarFilePath });
        const extracted = extractor.extract();
        const files = [...extracted.files]; // Converting the generator to an array
        const file = files.find(file => file.fileHeader.name === filename);

        if (file) {
            const fileBuffer = file.fileData; // Extrair o conteúdo do arquivo corretamente
            res.set('Content-Type', filename.endsWith('.png') ? 'image/png' : 'image/jpeg');
            res.send(fileBuffer); // Send the image as blob
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('File not found');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error extracting image:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error processing the RAR file');
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

index.html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RAR Image Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Images from RAR</h1>
    <div id="image-container"></div>

    <script>
        const imageContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');

        // Make a request to get the list of images
        fetch('/images')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(imageFilenames => {
                imageFilenames.forEach(filename => {
                    fetch(`/images/${filename}`)
                        .then(response => response.blob())
                        .then(blob => {
                            const img = document.createElement('img');
                            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // Create a URL for the blob
                            img.alt = filename;
                            img.style.width = '200px';
                            img.style.margin = '10px';
                            imageContainer.appendChild(img);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error loading the image:', error);
                        });
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading images:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Letting aside that your approach is horribly inefficient (you are reading and unpacking your archive for every request): "I've tried everything but haven't had success." is neither a sufficent description of your attempts nor of what actually happens ... How do you come to the conclusion, that it doesn't work? Any error messages? ...

Furthermore fs.readFileSync(rarFilePath) is highly discouraged in asynchronous environments because it effectifly blocks the whole process while a file is being read.

And the client side effectifly (more or less) kills your server because it sends a large amount of parallel image requests to your server. Leading to your server trying to load and unrar the same file over and over again. But that's not gonna work, because fs.readfileSync is blocking the whole process ...

@derpirscher  "Look, I modified the code; it shows the gallery, but the images are broken. When I load a RAR file divided into parts with many images, it takes a long time to load. With 'node-unrar-js', it's the closest I've come to what I want. When I said I've tried everything, I meant I've tried many libraries, and nothing has gotten me where I want to be, especially since I don't know much about how to do this. That's why I'm asking for help."

An excerpt from the error:
node server.js
Server running at http://localhost:3000
Extracted files: [
{
fileHeader: {
name: 'page005.png',
flags: [Object],
packSize: 8505,
unpSize: 10707,
crc: 2280051421,
time: '2015-11-19T12:18:46.000',
unpVer: '2.9',
method: 'Normal',
comment: ''
}
},

And this other attempt saved the images to disk; I don’t want to save them to disk.

Try the https://www.npmjs.com/package/unrar package (it seems more widely used and most importantly supports streaming)
// this is example code, maybe you'll need to list first, or check if file exists first, or this code will bug on missing file, or whatever
app.get('/images/:filename', async (req, res) => {
  const archive = new Unrar('/path/to/some/file.rar');
  // archive.list(function (err, entries) { ... }
  const stream = archive.stream('image1234.jpg'); // name of entry
  stream.on('error', (err) => res.status(404).send(err.message)));
  stream.pipe(res);
})


"Thank you for the tip, but I couldn't get it to work with your example, perhaps because I don't fully understand how to program. Thank you!"
